# How to reverse in modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given an RGB color {127, 255, 212} where scale is 0-255, VBA's `RGB` function find a long integer `x` such that

```
IntegerPart@{Mod[x,256],Mod[x/256,256],Mod[x/256^2,256]}
```

is equal to {127,255,212}. In this particular case the

```
x=13959039
```

How do i replicate this function in Mathematica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `NumberCompose`:

```
NumberCompose[{212,255,127},{256^2,256,1}]
```

> 13959039

Answer (score 3):

```
fromRGB[{r_, g_, b_}] := r + 256*g + 65536*b
fromRGB[{127, 255, 212}]
(* 13959039 *)
```

or

```
fromRGB[rgb_List] := {1, 256, 65536}.rgb
```

(same result)

Answer (score 3):

```
Reverse@IntegerDigits[13959039, 256]
FromDigits[Reverse@{127, 255, 212}, 256]
```

> {127, 255, 212}
>
> 13959039